# はたまた meaning at end of sentence

Tags: word-choice

I saw a sentence:

メガネの向こうで流れた一滴はお茶だったのか、**はたまた** - the drops that flowed on the guy (with glasses), is it tea

What does はたまた mean?

I looked at jisho and it means "or". But that can't possibly be the case here. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's just "or (else)", but the remaining part is left unsaid because it's obvious (涙だったのか) in this context. Isn't this possible also in English?

> お茶だったのか、はたまた…。
>   Was it tea, or...?